# Уведомление о пропущенном вызове

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

Когда то подрядчик правил `extensions_override_freepbx.conf` , чтобы приходили уведомления о пропущенном вызове в определенной очереди - стоял `freepbx12`. После обновления на 13й уведомления приходить перестали. Сама почта ходит, т.е. проблема не в постфиксе.

Ниже содержание файла:

```
[ext-queues]
exten => h,1,NoOp(Оповещение о пропущенном звонке на почту)
exten => h,n,Set(varTime=${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%H:%M:%S)})
exten => h,n,Set(varDate=${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%d-%m-%Y)})
exten => h,n,ExecIf($["${NODEST}"="101"]?Set(varQueueName="Отдел продаж"))
exten => h,n,ExecIf($["${NODEST}"="102"]?Set(varQueueName="Сервис"))
exten => h,n,ExecIf($["${CDR(dstchannel)}"=""]?System(echo -ne "Информация о `пропущенном звонке: \nОчередь: ${varQueueName} \nАбонент: ${CALLERID(num)}\nВремя: ${varTime} \nДата: ${varDate}" | mail -s "Пропущен звонок от абонента ${CALLERID(num)}" email@получателя))
exten => h,n,Macro(hangupcall,)
```

Наверняка дело в одной запятой или апострофе, потому и не хочется обращаться повторно к фрилансеру.
Тыкните носом, где ошибка.

Comment: Я бы для начала посмотрел в консоли, как оно проходится по этому контексту при обработке пропущенного. Проходится ли вообще? А там, возможно, решение станет очевидным.

Answer (score 0):

попробуй

```
exten => h,n,ExecIf($["${QUEUESTATUS}"!="CONTINUE"]?System(echo -ne "Информация о `пропущенном звонке: \nОчередь: ${varQueueName} \nАбонент: ${CALLERID(num)}\nВремя: ${varTime} \nДата: ${varDate}" | mail -s "Пропущен звонок от абонента ${CALLERID(num)}" email@получателя))
```

Comment: увы, без изменений

Comment: ExecIf($["${CDR(dstchannel)}"=""] не срабатывает, надо смотреть лог прохождения звонка чтоб понять проблему